# Detect that the browser is loading a new page to emphasize that something is happening

Tags: javascript, web

While UX-testing my various websites, I've often noticed that people have trouble identifying whether their "clicks" are actually doing anything.

There are multiple UI ways to handle this, like animating buttons to show they have been pushed, but I'd like to explore an alternative option.

I would like to animate my page with a loader when the browser begins to load a new page.

**Is this "loading new page" status available in JS ?** Can we use it for this sort of thing ? Are there any libraries built for this ?

Edit : many seem to confuse my question, which is understandable. So here's an attempt to clear things up.

**While on page A, I want to detect that a user has requested page B and is waiting for a server response. I would like to animate page A while waiting for the server response and first paint of page B.**

Comment: I think you mean: `How do I detect, if the status of the browser is: 'loading a new page right now'?`, not `How do I show a loading icon/spinner/progress bar?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980284/page-loading-status

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery.
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

You can show some image before loading some contents and hide it after document load.

Answer (score -1):

many libraries are available based on your language of implementation.

for a basic example, check [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp)

Answer (score -1):

I assume that only `<a>` tags redirect to page B so you can place a listener to all those `<a>` tags that show the animation and hide the rest of the page changing the state of the 'visibility style' with `object.style.visibility = "visible|hidden|collapse|initial|inherit"` before it redirects to B.

For example:

```
var linkList = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); // don't use it for all <a> tags. 
                                                   // Only for those that redirects to B

for(let i=0; i<linkList.length; i++){
    linkList[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = this.getAttribute('href');
        var target = this.getAttribute('target') || "_self";
        // show loading animation in here
        window.open(href,target);
    },false);
}
```

Comment: Hello @Carlos, I'm looking for a way to animate a page while the next page is loading, so more of an "exit" animation than an entry one !

Comment: Hi @Carlos and thanks for the edit. Won't this still cause the "back button" issue where if I navigate back to the page, I'll still see the animation running ?

Comment: @Brachamul As far as I've tried, it hasn't given me any problems even when you hit the "back" button on the browser. Make sure that the animation has the `display` property set to `none` in the html. E.g. `<div id="animation" style="display: none;">`